# Append Infinitos arrays retornados do PHP para o AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

```
function CheckNewsFeed() {
$.ajax({
  url: ProcurarPorNovosDados.php,
  success: function(texto) {
  *Aqui que está minha dúvida, como fazer o Append de resultados dinâmicos
  retornado pelo PHP?*
  //$("#Resultados").html(texto);
  }
})};

setTimeout(CheckNewsFeed(), 3000);
```

**Não tenho a mínima ideia de como fazer isto, nem sei se é possível, mas todo comentário ajuda, obrigado;**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O nome não podia ser mais convidativo: [`jQuery.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

```
// Como você utilizará #resultados infinitas vezes,
// coloque-o em cache, assim a busca no DOM ocorre apenas uma vez
var $resultados = $('#resultados');

function CheckNewsFeed() {
$.ajax({
    url: ProcurarPorNovosDados.php,
    success: function(texto) {
        $resultados.append(texto); // faz append do novo resultado
    }
})};

setTimeout(CheckNewsFeed(), 3000);
```

Comment: independente da lista de resultados no mysql?

Comment: Ao você configurar o callback success to método $.ajax já fica subentendido que você está retornando texto/html pronto para ser anexado na página, principalmente pois você não detalhou nada além disso. E, o jQuery não sabe nada sobre seu MySQL, tudo que ele espera ali é um retorno, não importa o que você faça no seu PHP. O que então você quer dizer com lista de resultados no MySQL? Como falei espera-se que no seu PHP você retorne apenas texto/html/JSON. Logo, se você obtém do MySQL, primeiro faça o tratamento no PHP e retorne o texto.

Comment: Sim, eu irei fazer com que os resultados tenham suas <div's> no próprio PHP, obrigado